# Products of the reaction between ethoxyethene and HI

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, ethers

#### Problem

> The products formed in the reaction
>
> $$\ce{CH2=CHOCH2CH3 + HI ->}$$
>
> are
>
> (**a**) $\ce{CH2=CHI}$ and $\ce{CH3CH2I}$
> (**b**) $\ce{CH2=CHI}$ and $\ce{CH3CH2OH}$
> (**c**) $\ce{CH3CHO}$ and $\ce{CH3CH2I}$
> (**d**) $\ce{CH3CH(I)OCH2CH3}$

#### Answer

> (**c**) $\ce{CH3CHO}$ and $\ce{CH3CH2I}$

#### Question

Does ether cleavage occur or electrophilic addition of $\ce{HI}$ to the double bond take place or both? I'm equally inclined towards both (**c**) and (**d**).

Comment: d is formed reversibly, then CH3CH(+)OCH2CH3 is cleaved by iodide.

Comment: The substrate is an enol ether, which is very sensitive to acid. And HI is a very strong acid, which can cleave usually stable normal ether linkages.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Why is the cleavage reaction favored over the electrophilic addition reaction? The cleavage reaction will proceed via breaking of a sigma bond whereas E+ addition proceeds via breaking a pi bond, so shouldn't E+ addition give a thermodynamically more stable product?

Comment: $$\ce{H2C=CH-O-CH2CH3 ->[H+] H3C-CH=O^+\!-CH2CH3 ->[I-]  H3C-CHO + I-CH2CH3}$$ The intermediate is more stable by resonance as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a mechanism for the cleavage. After proton transfer, the carbocation has a resonance contributor. Nucleophilic attack can occur on the ethyl group because there is a good leaving group.

[image]

The electrophilic addition can happen, with iodide attacking the carbocation. However, it is reversible. Iodide is a good leaving group, and the carbocation is resonance stabilized. The cleavage reaction is much less reversible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben, your answer made things absolutely clear